# How to crawl a website to get all the cookies which are set and the pages set them?

Tags: cookies, web-crawler

I am looking for a program which can crawl through a site and get a list of pages which set cookies. Normal site crawls do not parse JavaScript, so they won't pick up cookies set in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't find sutable tool. The best way is to write own script on GreasyMonkey (or another script engine plugin for browser) that search mask "****cookie****" and analyze results manually. Also you can write auto downloading and parsing external JS files for HTML page.